# grep output placed into a while loop

Tags: ksh, do-while, grep

I currently have my grep output configured to place everything in a file, i'm trying to set something up where a file will not need to be created.

```
    func_database () {
egrep "^[0-9]" file.txt | egrep "/ON /" | sed s/-[^@]*$// > /users/home/myhome/log/test.txt
}

                                    func_database
            while read -r line ; do
                                    echo "Database $line Area a:" 
            python amgr.py status $line a
            echo ""
                        echo "Database $line Area b:" 
            python amgr.py status $line b
            echo ""
                        echo "Database $line Area c:" 
            python amgr.py status $line c
            echo ""
            done </users/home/myhome/log/test.txt
```

Above is my current setup, is there anyway i can set something up where i will not need to send this information to the test.txt file prior to running it in the while;do function.
The python script will just output the status on screen. The test.txt file contains a list of numbers seperated by line for example

```
0
15
32
78
95
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe your output directly into the `while`:

```
func_database () {
    egrep "^[0-9]" file.txt | egrep "/ON /" | sed s/-[^@]*$//
}
func_database |
while read -r line
do
    echo "Database $line Area a:" 
    python amgr.py status $line a
    echo ""
    echo "Database $line Area b:" 
    python amgr.py status $line b
    echo ""
    echo "Database $line Area c:" 
    python amgr.py status $line c
    echo ""
done
```