# Processing next line of grep output in loop while previous function is sleeping

Tags: bash, loops, unix, grep, sleep

I have a piece of script that greps a temp file for an error message at the top of an if-loop. If an error is found, it then greps a few additional lines to gather more details, and then runs a process using those details. I echo the output on screen and tee it to a log file.

This script works well to step through any number of errors and run the process. The trouble is that the process requires a 60-second wait. There may be any number of errors found, from 0 to dozens. I need the routine to wait 60 seconds for the process against each error, but I would like it to go on and begin the process on the next error (if found) during the wait period on the previous error. So the process with the 60-second wait should happen near simultaneously with any number of errors.

This routine nests inside a larger script that runs every 5 minutes. So I need this part to wrap up in under 5 minutes, even if 5 or more errors are found.

```
if grep -q error todolist.temp; then
    echo "error(s) found"
    grep -A 3 tid todolist.temp | while read -r line ; do
        if [[ $line == "Item"* ]]; then
            myitem="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)"                     
        elif [[ $line == "Message"* ]]; then
            mymessage="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2-)"
            echo "----"
            echo $myitem "Error:" $mymessage | tee -a process.log 
            echo "Processing" $myitem | tee -a process.log 
            ./process START
            echo "Waiting 60 seconds..." | tee -a process.log 
            sleep 60
            ./process END
            echo "Process completed at `date +%H:%M:%S`" | tee -a process.log 
        fi
    done
fi
```

The output from this, if two example errors are found, is something like this:

```
error(s) found
----
Item 1 Error: Sample error text A
Processing Item 1
Waiting 60 seconds...
Process completed at 12:16:24
----
Item 2 Error: Sample error text B
Processing Item 2
Waiting 60 seconds...
Process completed at 12:17:24
```

I guess this means adding loop for the process wait outside (within?) the grep loop, but I'm stretching some new skills and I haven't figured it out.

These posts talk around my issue and some helped me get this far, but I'm still at a loss for getting each process to run simultaneously. Any help is appreciated.

[grep output placed into a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260416/grep-output-placed-into-a-while-loop)

[sleep a while loop based on output from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807474/sleep-a-while-loop-based-on-output-from-a-function)

Create an array perhaps? But I've only ever done that with python, which is not available to me here.
[Grep outputs multiple lines, need while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216129/grep-outputs-multiple-lines-need-while-loop)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102956/how-to-run-a-command-in-the-background-with-a-delay --  Just `(sleep 60; ./process END) &` and make sure you add a `wait` after `done` if you want to ensure you wait for the last ones.  The parens create a subshell.  The ampersand backgrounds it so that your script can continue.

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I needed to know. The only addition to make it complete is that the echo "Process completed" line also goes inside the subshell in order to make sense. Thanks so much for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [stevesliva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3120884/stevesliva).
Updated code with this subshell line works perfectly:

```
(sleep 60; ./process END; echo "Process completed at `date +%H:%M:%S`") &
```